# $\mu_{\alpha} \ll \mu$ in $P(S), \frac{d\mu_{\alpha}}{d\mu}$ uniformly integrable $\Rightarrow \{\mu_{\alpha, \alpha \in I}\}$ is relatively compact.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, compactness, weak-convergence

I want to prove the following result which I found in the book cited at the end of this post:

> **Theorem 2.3.2:** Let $\{\mu_{\alpha, \alpha \in I}\} \in P(S)$ satisfy: $\mu_{\alpha} \ll \mu$ for all $\alpha \in I$ and a prescribed $\mu \in P(S).$ Suppose $\frac{d\mu_{\alpha}}{d\mu}, \alpha \in I,$ are uniformly integrable with respect to $\mu.$ Then $\{\mu_{\alpha, \alpha \in I}\}$ is relatively compact.

Here $P(S)$ is a space of probability measures on a Polish space $(S,d)$, with complete metric $d$ taking values in $[0,1].$ While, $\mathscr F$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $S$.  I wanted to see if there are any errors in my proof. So here it is:

> $\textit{Proof.}$ By Radon-Nikodym theorem, we have
> $\frac{d\mu_{\alpha}}{d\mu}=f_{\alpha}$ for some $f_{\alpha} \in
>  L_1(S, \mathscr F, \mu),$i.e., we have $\mu_{\alpha}(E)=\int_E
>  f_{\alpha} d\mu$ for all $E \in \mathscr F.$ Since the family $\{\frac{d\mu_{\alpha}}{d\mu}, \alpha \in
>  I\}=\{f_{\alpha}\}$ is uniformly integrable with respect to $\mu$, by
> using Dunford-Pettis theorem every sequence in $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ has a
> further weakly convergent subsequence. Consider a sequence $(f_n) \in \{f_{\alpha}\}$. Then it has a weakly
> convergent subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converging to some $f \in L_1(S,
>  \mathscr F, \mu)$. Thus, $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int f_{n_k}g d\mu=\int
>  fg d\mu \; \forall \; g \in L_{\infty}(S,\mathscr F,\mu) \Rightarrow
>  \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_E f_{n_k} d\mu=\int_E f d\mu \; \forall \; E
>  \in \mathscr F \Rightarrow \lim_{k \to \infty}\mu_{n_k}(E) =
>  \mu_{n_{\infty}}(E) \; \forall \; E \in \mathscr F.$ Thus we have proved that every sequence in $\{\mu_{\alpha}\}$ has a further convergent subsequence. Hence the family $\{\mu_{\alpha}\}$ is
> relatively compact in $P(S).$

I am suspicious about my proof since I get the very last equality for all $E \in \mathscr F$ and not for all $E \in \mathscr F$ with $\mu_{n_{\infty}}(\partial E)=0,$ which makes me think that I have a proof that is somewhat overkill.

> *Borkar, Vivek S.*, Probability theory. An advanced course, New York, NY: Springer-Verlag. x, 145 p. (1995). [ZBL0838.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0838.60001).

Comment: This is correct. What you have is stronger than weak convergence but weaker than total variation convergence of the subsequence.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I also saw that I had got an in-between convergence.